# Spark sql when joining two or more tables using two select statements

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is my statement:

```
val Porders = sqlContext.sql(
    """SELECT count(STATUS_CD) 
    FROM s_order 
    WHERE STATUS_CD = 'pending' AND ROW_ID IN 
        ( SELECT so.ROW_ID FROM s_order so 
        JOIN s_order_item soi 
        ON so.ROW_ID = soi.ORDER_ID 
        JOIN s_order_type sot 
        ON so.ORDER_TYPE_ID = sot.ROW_ID 
        JOIN s_product sp 
        ON soi.PROD_ID = sp.ROW_ID
        WHERE (sp.NAME like '%VIP%' OR sp.NAME like '%BIZ%' OR sp.NAME like '%UniFi%') 
        AND LOWER(sot.NAME) = 'new install')
    """)
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR : java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.3] failure: identifier expected
( SELECT so.ROW_ID FROM s_order so JOIN s_order_item soi 
  ^
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, why this happens, is that subqueries are not supported: see [Spark-4226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4226).

Even a query like

```
sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT count(STATUS_CD)
     FROM s_order
     WHERE STATUS_CD = 'pending' AND ROW_ID IN
       (SELECT * FROM s_order)
  """)
```

does not work currently (speaking of Spark SQL 1.5.1)

Try to *replace your subquery by a join*, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Comment: Thank u ... Martin Senne

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget the up-vote or answer accept ;)

Comment: How to use subquery in FROM clause in spark sql